# How can I create a predefined group with permissions?

Tags: python, django

I want to create several groups with predefined permissions. But I can not find how to do it.

`auth` application use `post_migrate` to create permissions. So I can't use the signal because I can't be sure that my callback will be called after the `auth`. For the same reason, I can't do it in migration.

Comment: you mean programmatically? Or through the admin panel?

Comment: yes, programmatically

Comment: Do you want to fill your database with some groups?

Comment: Yes. But before run the server (like "migration").